# Common-mode choke on LTSpice

Tags: ltspice, three-phase, inductance, common-mode-choke, mutual-inductance

Can someone suggest to me how to select a three-phase common-mode choke with self and mutual inductance in LTSpice?

Comment: For a reference, search for `3-phase_transformer.asc` in the the [LTspice group](https://groups.io/g/LTspice/) Files/. area (registration needed to avoid spamming, but it's only a formality).

Comment: @ a concerned citizen, I have registered to the group and searched. no result.

Answer (score 1):

A CM choke (transformer) can be modeled by using inductors with the K statement. for further you can see the following link
https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-basic-steps-for-simulating-transformers.html

Comment: That will not work for 3-phase. BTW, you probably searched in the Messages area, not the Files/ section, as I said, otherwise you would have seen it's the first hit. Do try again, you'll see why I said your link does not apply to 3-phase: the flux cancles for balanced input, and gives erroneous results for imbalanced conditions.

Comment: @a concerned citizen, I got it now. thank you so much. But my concern is that a three-phase transformer has six windings. However, there are just three windings in the CM choke. So, do you believe the three-phase transformer model can replace the CM choke?

Comment: The number of windings should not be your concern, only the functionality. In this case, it might work, you have to test it for yourself. BTW, when using the ping operator, `@`, use it with `<TAB>` to cycle between the names. There should be no spaces. If there are no names to cycle, then there's no need for `@`, but only then.

Comment: @Ady did you figure this out? I cannot find the file being referred to here, and I am stuck on a similar problem myself. Please let me know how you could simulate three phase common mode choke on LTspice successfully.